# Uninstall gcc from source

Tags: linux, uninstall, gcc

For fun, I compiled and installed gcc 4.7.2 in ~/build, which contains bin, doc, lib, include, man, share, et al. directories, all of which are added to the appropriate environment variables.

Now I want to remove it, so it can stop shadowing my v4.4.7 /usr/bin/gcc with all its associated libraries and whatnot (whatever they may be), but, of course, the GCC make files
offer no uninstall target, and `find ~/bin -iname "\*gcc*"` turns up quite a bit.

Is my only option to set the prefix to some temporary directory, run the installation again, then use than new set of files as a guide for deleting the old ones? Or is there a better way?

This is on Springdale Linux 6.4 (Pisa), kernel 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64, and I do not have root access.

Comment: Did you run a `make install`? From your question it sounds like everything is in subdirectories of `~/build` and deleting that dir is all you need.

Comment: That is true (the compiler executable for instance is at `~/build/bin/gcc`) but, since I don't have root access on this machine, I use this directory extensively to install software for my user. Clearly I should have put the GCC install in its own subdirectory to begin with, but I did not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303928/how-to-uninstall-gcc-installed-from-source || http://askubuntu.com/questions/101471/how-to-uninstall-gcc-4-6-2

Answer (score 0):

In GCC 5.1.0, the best method so far is to install it somewhere else with `DESTDIR` and then use that to decide which files were generated, as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25304014/895245

Although there is no top-level `uninstall` target, some directories do have it, in particular `gcc`, so you can do:

```
cd build/gcc
sudo make uninstall
```

This does not remove everything that was installed, but it removes major executables like `gcc`, `g++`, `cpp`... contained in that directory, so it might be enough.